# Microsoft graph api app throwing error Code: Authorization_RequestDenied Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

[image: My microsoft graph app permissions]

I am using microsoft graph api app to pull employee information and I am not Azure admin. Admin in my organization has authorized me attached permissions. Even with grated permissions am getting error,
Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

I am getting Client correctly.
Can you please help to resolve this error ?

Comment: Which endpoint do you access? /users? How do you authenticate?

Comment: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note** that: To access user information, you need to generate access token by passing **`User.Read.All`** scope.

Created a Microsoft Entra ID application:

[image]

Generated **access token** by using below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=token+id_token
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=fragment
&scope=openid offline_access User.Read.All
&state=12345
&nonce=12345
```

***Access and ID tokens generated successfully:***

[image]

If you make use of ID token to access user information you will get **`401`** error, hence **make use of access token to fetch user details**.

Decode the access token and make sure that the **aud** is Microsoft Graph and **`User.Read.All`** scope is present:

[image]

Pass the above access token, and **I am able to access token user information successfully**:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=DisplayName,EmployeeId,employeeHireDate,employeeLeaveDateTime,employeeType
```

[image]

Comment: I am using a Microsoft graph application with a client ID and secret ID.  The way you generated the token looks very different than the way I generated it. Is this for the Microsoft graph API application?

Comment: Yes it is for Microsoft Graph Api application

Comment: Can you decode the token in jwt.ms and check if the roles exist